# Remove duplicates based on specific column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table #temp where I need to remove some duplicates based on a column (Tariff_Value)value.

Below is the SQL fiddle and i have populated the random values.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
[acctnumber] varchar(50),
[Premnumber] varchar(50),
x varchar(5),
y varchar(5),
z varchar(5),
w varchar(5),
[Tariff_value] varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('1234228','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 5M PRIVATE AREA sndfwsme')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('1234228','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 2M SM GEN SVC sdfuaisdfbeu')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('3237329','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 5M PRIVATE AREA sndfwsme')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('3237329','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 2M SM GEN SVC sdfuaisdfbeu')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('6541835','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 2M SM GEN SVC sdfuaisdfbeu')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('6541835','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 2Mdf SM GEN SVC sdfuaisdfbeu')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('7545322','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 8Msd SM GEN SVC sdfuaisdfbeu')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('7545322','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 2M SM GEN SVC sdfuaisdfbeu')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('8548235','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 5M PRIVATE AREA sndfwsme')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('8548235','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 5M12 PRIVATE AREA sndfwsme')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('5482312','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 5M6552 PRIVATE AREA sndfwsme')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('5482312','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 5M PRIVATE AREA sndfwsme')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('7589631','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 5M PRIVATE AREA sndfwsme')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('7589631','234233','x','y','z','w','RATE 2M SM GEN SVC sdfuaisdfbeu')
```

The output of the query should be 
[image]

I need a query where the below logic could be implemented or any efficient CROSS APPLY logic to get these if possible is much appreciated.

```
;WITH cte1 AS
(
SELECT [acctnumber], [Premnumber],x,y,z,w,count(*) AS cnt FROM #temp
GROUP BY [acctnumber], [Premnumber],x,y,z,w
)
,

SELECT a.* FROM #temp a INNER JOIN cte1 b ON a.acctnumber = b.acctnumber AND a.Premnumber = b.Premnumber
WHERE (if b.cnt >1 then FETCH record from #temp table exclude tarriff_value like '%2M%' and fetch tarriff_value like '%5M%'  )
```

Problem: The output query should not exclude 2M records if there is no 5M records associated with it.Subsequently, it should exclude 2M from (2M and 5M) records.

Literally in a visual explanation

[image]

Comment: is the acctnumber always in pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do it. Didn't use cross apply just basic left joins.

```
select * 
from #temp t
left join 
(select acctnumber, Tariff_value
from #temp
where Tariff_value like '% 2M %') t1
on t.acctnumber = t1.acctnumber 
and t.Tariff_value = t1.Tariff_value
left join 
(select acctnumber, Tariff_value
from #temp
where Tariff_value like '% 5M %') t2
on t1.acctnumber = t2.acctnumber 
where t2.acctnumber is null
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an indicator to mark a record as 1 when 5M while 2 for 2M. if the sum of this indicator is 3 then it is the pair 5M and 2M.  I use join to filter this against the original table. see demo in sqlfiddle; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0754/6

```
select t.*
from temp t join (
select acctnumber,
sum(case when Tariff_value like '%5M%'
 then 1 
 when Tariff_value like '%2M%'
 then 2 else 0 end) as is_pair
from temp
group by acctnumber) s
on t.acctnumber=s.acctnumber
 where s.is_pair <> 3
  or (s.is_pair=3 
      and t.Tariff_value like '%5M%');
```